# Output None in function

Tags: python, function, output, expression, nonetype

why here the output of `my_func` is None? I assign an integer to `x` then I have an expression in local scope.

```
Def my_func():
       x=4
       x**2
Print(my_func())
```

Output: `None`

Comment: because `x**2` just evaluates to 16, but you're not doing anything with this number `16`. You need to `return` it, which will pass back `16` to your function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't write any return statement then the function returns `None`
So you return the value you want to print or else print it in the function itself or else use lambda function as follows

```
print((lambda x: x**2)(4))
```

So simple right!!
Have a look at OOPS concepts and lambda functions of Python to know more

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the result of the expression from your function, so it returns `None` by default:

```
def my_func():
    x = 4
    return x ** 2

print(my_func())
```

Output:

```
16
```